# How to filter certain fields in Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have two models, one is **Product** and second is **paymentInvoice** that are connected by a foreign key.

I want to get all the invoice details where the product field has the qty_amount='20L'.

**Product Model**

```
class Product(models.Model):

    Qty_Choices = (
        ('250ml', '250ml'),
        ('500ml', '500ml'),
        ('1L', '1L'),
        ('5L', '5L'),
        ('20L', '20L')
        )
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    available = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(default='default_product.jpg', upload_to='product_photos')
    category = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    qty_amount = models.CharField(
        max_length=20, choices=Qty_Choices, default='250ml')
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

**paymentInvoice Model**

```
class paymentInvoice(models.Model):
    class paymentStatus(models.TextChoices):
        PENDING = 'Pending'
        PAID = 'Paid'
        DELIVERED = 'Delivered'
    
    class paymentMode(models.TextChoices):
        MPESA = 'Mpesa'
        BANK = 'Bank'
        CHEQUE = 'Cheque'
        CASH = 'Cash'

    shipping_address_owner = models.ForeignKey(
        ShippingAddress, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="customer_invoice")
    product = models.ManyToManyField(
        Product, related_name='product_invoice')
    mode = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=paymentMode.choices, default=paymentMode.MPESA)
    date = models.DateField(default=datetime.now)
    invoice_id = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    quantity = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    status = models.CharField(
        max_length=20, choices=paymentStatus.choices, default=paymentStatus.PENDING)
    total_payment = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=2)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.shipping_address_owner.customer.name
```

My **views.py** file for my invoice is displayed below.

```
class paymentInvoiceListCreateView(ListCreateAPIView):
    """
    ListCreateAPIView executes both 'GET' and 'POST' requests. i.e listing a queryset or creating a model instance.
    """
    serializer_class = paymentInvoiceSerializer
    queryset = paymentInvoice.objects.order_by(
        '-date').filter(product.qty_amount="20L")
```

The filter method i used above does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is inside the filter. Can you try this.

```
class paymentInvoiceListCreateView(ListCreateAPIView):
    """
    ListCreateAPIView executes both 'GET' and 'POST' requests. i.e listing a queryset or creating a model instance.
    """
    serializer_class = paymentInvoiceSerializer
    queryset = paymentInvoice.objects.filter(product__qty_amount="20L").order_by('-date')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class paymentInvoiceListCreateView(ListCreateAPIView):
    """
    ListCreateAPIView executes both 'GET' and 'POST' requests. i.e listing a queryset or creating a model instance.
    """
    serializer_class = paymentInvoiceSerializer
    queryset = paymentInvoice.objects.filter(product__qty_amount="20L").all()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class paymentInvoiceListCreateView(ListCreateAPIView):
    """
    ListCreateAPIView executes both 'GET' and 'POST' requests. i.e listing a queryset or creating a model instance.
    """
    serializer_class = paymentInvoiceSerializer
    queryset = paymentInvoice.objects.all()

    def get_queryset(self):
        return self.queryset.filter(product__qty_amount="20L").order_by('-date') \
            # .values(qty_amount=F('product__qty_amount')) if you want to change your field name in response
```

implement get_querysset method. This might help

Comment: Kindly explain this line **.values(qty_amount=F('product__qty_amount')) if you want to change your field name in response ***

Comment: there is django in build feature you can direct apply functions like F, Q, etc etc on .filter(method)

ex suppose you don't apply F function then your response will look like: 
{ ..., 'product__qty_amount'; "20L", ...}   but by using F function your response will look like { ..., 'qty_amount'; "20L", ...}

you simply can modify your response obj as per requirements

Comment: for better search you can visit https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/expressions/